# How do I work on my training period feedback?

Tags: software-industry, developer, training, probation

After my probation period of 3 months I have received feedback from my manager as I am good at understanding concepts lack in technical implementation. Also I need to better both my quality and quantity of work. How should I work about it before my next review after three months
Note: I am working as a web designer

Edit: I have been asked to learn technically and be strong in the basics first. In my job my main skillset is coding (HTML5,CSS). I am asking how should I approach towards the review and accomplish his feedback.  I wish to turn from inexperienced person to competent member in the team.

Comment: VTC, way too broad, we need better details to even begin to consider how to help

Comment: Are you asking how to accomplish the goals that your boss set in your review?  Perhaps update the question with some specific criticisms he had and we can suggest ways to address them.  Or you can always ask him.

Comment: ya @JasonJ hopefuly my edit helps you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with quality, quantity will come once the quality is there. Ask your boss for specific examples of things that you need to learn first. Then learn them. More importantly, retain what you learned.

I have never worked with a good performer who had to look things up continually. Some things that aren't used very often, yes.  But you can't improve your speed until you retain information and start to be able to use what you have learned in new situations.

Comment: I would add that anyone in this position must examine whether they were hired above their skillset, or is just having trouble applying that skillset to the job at hand. In the second case, learn those things at work with well-tuned questions. In the first case, though, you must plan to learn more than usual at home as well.